# How to implement a view model that wraps a model's property

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

Assume a model that comes with a property called `Value`. The model implements `INotifyPropertyChanged`. Next, assume a view model that knows the model and offers itself a property `Value` to a imaginary view. This view model is implemented as follows:

**View model code snippet**

```
public int Value
{
    get {
        Model.Value;
    }
    set {
        if(value != Model.Value) {
            Model.Value = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
}
```

I.e. the whole purpose of the view at this point is to directly pass a property of the model to the view.

The view model is registered to the model's `PropertyChanged` events. Every time `Value` of the model changes, the view model notices the change and triggers a `PropertyChanged` event itself so that a view that binds to the view model's property `Value` knows to update itself.

This leads to multiple `PropertyChanged` calls If one changes the model via the view model:

1. Once in the code of the view model that listens to changes of the model after executing `Model.Value = value;`
2. And again inside the setter of `Value` due to `OnPropertyChanged();`

The only solution that comes to my mind is to completly separate the view model from the model. This includes holding a complete clone of the model's data. This way I can avoid the first call of `PropertyChanged`. Because I'm able to compare the value of the view model with the value of the model I can distinguish between different sources of the change (i.e. view model changed model or model was changed by another source).

Note that the view model is far more complex. Merging the model with the view model is not a solution.

Comment: I don't think you completed your title...

Comment: Sorry, I fixed it.

Comment: I'd say the viewmodel should be in charge of updating the model, and the model should not implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`. Who besides the viewmodel is changing the model? Other models? Other viewmodels?

Comment: This question is fundamentally flawed. There **should be** multiple notifications, if both objects have INotifyPropertyChanged. One notifies anyone listening to ViewModel's property. The other notifies anyone listening to Model's corresponding property. These are typically different subscribers. If you remove one of those notifications, you risk breaking code during some future maintenance change, by someone expecting a notification.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If the view model is already registered to the model's property changed and in turn raises its own property change then there is not a need for `OnPropertyChanged()` in the property of the view model.

Remove `OnPropertyChanged()`

ViewModel code would look like.

```
public int Value {
    get {
        return Model.Value;
    }
    set {
        if(value != Model.Value) {
            Model.Value = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I already thought about this, but this doesn't seem right because it's an indirect mechanism.

Comment: I disagree. The goal was to notify the view. You did that by subscribing to the model's property changed event. saving having to do it manually in the view model. No need to over complicate things

Comment: I guess you're right. I found the article http://geekswithblogs.net/DavidVallens/archive/2011/04/01/writing-mvvm-viewmodel-wrappers---part-1.aspx that somewhat goes in the same direction.

Comment: This seems very backwards  to me. "No need to overcomplicate things"? The viewmodel is using the model as a mechanism to raise `PropertyChanged`. If you've got two implementations of `INotifyPropertyChanged`, and you only want one, and one of them is the viewmodel, get rid of the one that isn't.

Comment: I must agree with @EdPlunkett.  The model is just a repository of data (I think of it as a database, but just because I use them a lot) that does not know how to change itself. So the view model is there to navigate changes to the model coming from the view, as well as parsing the model for presentation in the view (again based on interaction coming from the view).

Comment: @PaulGibson I agree as well. But we are not always in control of the model. There are instance where the model may be inherited from INotifyPropertyChanged. While not the best solution or my first choice. I can work. In some instance I do an anti-pattern and just expose the model via the view model and bind directly to the model from the view like `{Bind Model.PropertyName}`. Is not pretty but works.

Comment: @Nkosi Just because somebody implemented `INotifyPropertyChanged` doesn't mean you have to turn you own design into a confusing mess. You're looking for excuses to do it wrong. That's not a good way to think about programming.

Comment: This answer has a fatal flaw. Any code listening for changes to ViewModel's property **will not be notified of the change**.

Answer (score 2):

The viewmodel should be in charge of updating the view and updating the model.

You've essentially identified the reason why the model shouldn't implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`, and shouldn't do anything that requires it to. There isn't a clean, normal MVVM way to do what you're trying to do. That suggests that you're doing MVVM wrong. MVVM isn't holy writ, of course, but it does work well and what you're doing instead has already gotten you into trouble. You've created a problem you didn't need to create, and there are no good solutions to it. The answer isn't to choose the least-worst solution; it's to go back and eliminate the problem from the design.

This design is fundamentally ill-conceived and any attempt to salvage it by adding further complexity will be a mess. It was worth doing because you learned from it, but it's not worth investing any more time in.

The answer to your literal question, "how to implement a viewmodel [property] that wraps a model's property", is:

**Just like you did it in your `public int Value` example, but without the model implementing `INotifyPropertyChanged`.**

Comment: If you have multiple view models that operate on the same model that does not implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`, how do you know about changes? Do you suggest that the view models have to notify each other?

Comment: @lcm That doesn't sound like a good idea to me. We have one place in an application I work on at work where we couldn't avoid it, and the users understand that they have to refresh. Hasn't been an issue.